# Traffic not routed to nginx ingress when we add inbound rules in Amazon load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, kubernetes, amazon-elb

We have Jenkins deployed as a pod using nginx ingress behind AWS classic load balancer. When we are open to internet , We are able to hit the jenkins URL. But when we add specific IP in inbound rules of the load balancer, traffic is not reached to ingress . Please find the ingress definition. Please help to solve the issue

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx-external-ingress
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
  name: external-auth-oauth2
  namespace: cicd
spec:
  rules:
  - host: jenkins.xyz.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: jenkins
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /generic-webhook-trigger/invoke
```

Comment: You probably want to add some more information. What does you Lb config/lb inbound rule look like, what error exactly are you getting. does anything pop up in your ingress logs at all and so on.

Comment: In inbound , added a ip for port 443. I am getting 500 as response. I am not seeing any pop up

Comment: @RickRackow I tried to access from the ip added in security group - inbound for port 443, I am getting 500 and page is not loading

Comment: @RickRackow no logs in ingress pod too